# Running SQL COUNT code - Missing parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, sqlplus

I'm trying to run this SQL command but it's giving me an error that the SQL command is not properly ended. Note, I'm using Oracle's 11g.

```
SELECT BookTitle.btName, BookTitle.Isbn FROM BookTitle AND SELECT COUNT(Isbn)
FROM BookTitle
JOIN Loan ON (Borrower.borId = Loan.borId)
JOIN BookCopy ON (Loan.bcId = BookCopy.bcId)
JOIN Authorship ON (BookCopy.isbn = Authorship.isbn)
JOIN Author ON (Author.authorID = Authorship.authorID)
WHERE Loan
ORDER BY Loan.dateOut DESC;
```

Can you kindly guide me to what's wrong ?

[image]

have several tables Book Title, BookCopy, Authorship, Loan, Author, Publisher and Borrower. I need to find the most borrowed book and list all titles and isbn.

```
BookTitle contains ISBN(PK), btName, datePublished, pubId*, ageLower, ageUpper, value.
Borrower contains borID(PK), borName, borAddress and borMaxbook
BOokCopy cvontains bcID(PK), ISBN*, dateAcquired, dateDestroyed
oan contains borID(PH)*, bcID(OK)*, dateOut(FK), dateDue and dateBack
Publisher contains PubId(PK), pubName and pubAddress
Publisher cotains PubID(8), pubName, pubAddress
Authoer contains authorID(PK) and authorName
Authorship contains authorId*, and ISBN*
```

Comment: You seem to have stuck one query inside another. The "and select count ..." is certainly not allowed in standard SQL

Comment: Please don't post screenshots from the console. Copy and paste the ouptut instead and use the <pre> tag to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      BookTitle.btName  AS bookName
    , BookTitle.isbn    AS ISBN
    , COUNT(*)          AS numberOfLoans 
FROM 
        BookTitle  
    JOIN 
        BookCopy   ON BookCopy.isbn = BookTitle.isbn
    JOIN 
        Loan       ON Loan.bcId = BookCopy.bcId
    JOIN 
        Borrower   ON Borrower.borId = Loan.borId
GROUP BY 
      BookTitle.btName
    , BookTitle.isbn
ORDER BY 
      MAX(Loan.dateOut) DESC         --- order by latest loan
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but the values arent sorted by popularity.

Comment: `ORDER BY numberOfLoans DESC`

Comment: @ypercube - Does this need the Author and Authorship tables?  Brian - Is this a homework question?

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: It seems that no columns from these two tables are wanted. If they were, we'd have a problem, we couldn't use `JOIN Authorship` as it probably has a 1-to-many relationship with `BookTitle` and the count would show wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT BookTitle.btName, BookTitle.Isbn, COUNT(Isbn) FROM BookTitle
JOIN Loan ON (Borrower.borId = Loan.borId)
JOIN BookCopy ON (Loan.bcId = BookCopy.bcId)
JOIN Authorship ON (BookCopy.isbn = Authorship.isbn)
JOIN Author ON (Author.authorID = Authorship.authorID)
-- WHERE Loan (Commented out because its not ended properly)
ORDER BY Loan.dateOut DESC;
```

**EDIT**: It also appears all your tables are wrong.  Your `JOIN`'s are referring to tables that do not exist in your `FROM` statement

**EDIT2**: It appears your `JOIN`'s are either intended to be simple joins or are not properly syntax'd more complex joins.  Please research [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) about `JOIN` types.  For a simple join use this example:

```
SELECT BookTitle.btName, BookTitle.Isbn, SELECT COUNT(Isbn) FROM BookTitle, Borrower, Loan, BookCopy, Authorship, Author
WHERE (Borrower.borId = Loan.borId)
AND (Loan.bcId = BookCopy.bcId)
AND (BookCopy.isbn = Authorship.isbn)
AND (Author.authorID = Authorship.authorID)
ORDER BY Loan.dateOut DESC;
```

**EDIT 3**: Check [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) AND [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) for info on how to build your joins properly

Comment: That I guess works but I get a new error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: @Brian Its because of your WHERE statement is not ended properly.  Try this:  `SELECT BookTitle.btName, BookTitle.Isbn, COUNT(Isbn) FROM BookTitle
JOIN Loan ON (Borrower.borId = Loan.borId)
JOIN BookCopy ON (Loan.bcId = BookCopy.bcId)
JOIN Authorship ON (BookCopy.isbn = Authorship.isbn)
JOIN Author ON (Author.authorID = Authorship.authorID)
ORDER BY Loan.dateOut DESC;`

Comment: ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "BORROWER"."BORID": invalid identifier

Comment: @Brian - It also appears your tables are wrong because your `JOIN`'s do not reference tables in your `FROM` statement

Comment: I did not understand what you're saying. Basically to 'get to' other tables I have to join multiple tables

Comment: @Brian - Actually use this statement:

Comment: So basically I have to add the other tables in the FROM ?

Comment: It's giving me a missing expression at line 1, after Author. I guess I have to put everything in brackets?

Comment: @Brian: Actually try this statement, it uses `SIMPLE` joins (if that is what you need)  If you need a different join type do some research [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) to determine what kind you need.  `SELECT BookTitle.btName, BookTitle.Isbn, SELECT COUNT(Isbn) FROM BookTitle, Borrower, Loan, BookCopy, Authorship, Author
WHERE (Borrower.borId = Loan.borId)
AND (Loan.bcId = BookCopy.bcId)
AND (BookCopy.isbn = Authorship.isbn)
AND (Author.authorID = Authorship.authorID)
ORDER BY Loan.dateOut DESC;`

Comment: The JOIN works because I used this statement prevoiusly and it worked. `SELECT Borrower.borName FROM Borrower
JOIN Loan ON (Borrower.borId = Loan.borId)
JOIN BookCopy ON (Loan.bcId = BookCopy.bcId)
JOIN Authorship ON (BookCopy.isbn = Authorship.isbn)
JOIN Author ON (Author.authorID = Authorship.authorID)
WHERE Author.authorName = 'Phillip Pullman' AND loan.dateback is null;` The one you gave me didnt work

Comment: @Brian - Im not sure what you are trying to do.  The question originally posted did not have any detail, but only included a SQL statement that was not correct.  I cannot provide you with a valid SQL statement without knowing what you are trying to do, what values are in the tables and how you are expecting to join them.  If I were you I would start over with your SQL query with 1 table, then slowly add your additional tables

Comment: I have several tables Book Title, BookCopy, Authorship, Loan, Author, Publisher and Borrower. I need to find the most borrowed book and list all titles and isbn

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6405/discussion-between-professionalamateur-and-brian)

Comment: That doesnt give me enough info.  Check [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) AND [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) for info on how to build your joins properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the AND in the first line and the "Loan" in the WHERE clause...  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to Get the ISBN and Title of Each book from the BookTitle table and count the number of books and then get the 'most popular' book from the Loan table

Comment: Can you edit your original question to add a couple rows of sample data from each table and what you want your desired output to be?

Comment: How do these tables link to the table BookTitle?  And again, what do you want your final output to look like (not a description, but actually show some rows of what you want to end up with)?